# Linking 2 tables together and join statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create two tables that are linked. My questions is would this design work and would my join statement work.

Table #1 banquet hall
id(PK),
name,
location,
etc

Table #2 Reservation
id(PK),
Banquet_hall_id(FK),
days reserved,
etc

If I want to get reservation values and hotel values together would the following SQL work?

```
select from reservation where id = 1 inner join on banquet_hall_id = banquenthall.id
```

What I am hoping is this would select values from banquet hall(name, location, etc) and also select values from reservation such as days reserved, etc

Answer (score 0):

Yes the design looks correct since there will be a `1..*` relationship between hall and reservation but your query is bit upside down. It should look like

```
select r.*, h.name, h.location
from reservation r
join hall h
on r.banquet_hall_id = h.id
where h.id = 1;
```

Comment: What I wanted to do was actually select everything using reservation id

Answer (score 0):

When joining two tables, remember that one is normally the **parent** (the one with the Primary Key you are linking) and the other is the **child** (the one with the foreign key).

An SQL statement with a `JOIN` clause takes the following pattern:

```
select *
from child inner join parent on child.fk = parent.pk
```

where `fk` is the foreign key and `pk` is the primary key.

Since both `JOIN` and `=` are symmetrical, you can write them either way. For example:

```
select *
from parent inner join child on child.fk = parent.pk
```

In your case, this results in:

```
select *
from reservation inner join banquethall on banquet_hall_id = banquenthall.id
```

(I assume that your table `banquet hall` is really `banquethall`: otherwise you would need to double-quote the name: `"banquet hall"`).

A `WHERE` clause *always* follows the table expression. In your case:

```
select *
from reservation inner join banquethall on banquet_hall_id = banquenthall.id
where reservation.id=1;
-- where banquethall.id=1;
```

Since you are joining table which have duplicated column names (`id`), you must qualify the ambiguous column name.

Comment: What I actually wanted to do was select everything using reservation id

Comment: @okaSKR It should work if you change the last line as above.